# What is default google analytics session timeout for Android mobile app?

Tags: android, google-analytics

Android GA documentation is bit confusing

The Java api says default timeout is 30 seconds.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/Tracker.html#setSessionTimeout(long)

However same document says ga_sessionTimeout is 1800 which is 30 minutes.

`ga_sessionTimeout(int) - time (in seconds) an app can stay in the background before a new session is started. Setting this to a negative number will result in a new session never being started. Default is 1800 seconds (30 minutes).`

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/sessions

And my actual experiment shows that this timeout is 300 seconds. Does anyone know what is the timeout value for session is for Android application? Unfortunately Tracker object doesn't have get method, or any other methods to figure out the value could me.

Comment: I'm having the same issue/confusion. Did you get an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

What is your Google Analytics Session Timeout setting on? Go to Admin > Property column (middle column) > JS Tracking info > Session Settings

The default timeout is 30 minutes, *unless someone has changed the timeout value*.

I am very well-versed with Google Analytics from an administrative standpoint, and I have found that the documentation is somewhat misleading at times. The default value is not static, contrary to what the Google Docs imply.